# Should I inline all CSS and JS for a static SPA?

Tags: javascript, html, css, gruntjs, bundling-and-minification

I am creating a Single Page Application that consists of only static HTML, JS and CSS. I need to support IE9+, modern desktop browsers and iOS 6+.

The web is built using grunt, and I'm considering inlining all JS and CSS the HTML file, which would simplify handling a little bit.

As there is no server-generated content, and the .html page is cached as well, do you see any pitfalls or drawbacks when inlining all JS and CSS? As far as I understand it could even increase performance, as there are fewer roundtrips for the browser, but maybe there are some good reasons to not inline those (quite huge) files?

Do you have any experiences with this?

**[Edit]**
It seems to be quite unclear. I do **not** want to manually put all JS and CSS I am working with in the resulting HTML file. I have a clean project structure, and think about letting grunt generate an inlined version as release output. I won't work with the inlined version, neither for developing nor for debugging. My question is only about the technical part: Will there be any negative influence on the browser (except for caching, the whole *html* is cached, and I can live with invalidating it as a whole)? Why is inlining as a result of an automated build process still considered bad practice (except for the caching topic)?

Comment: Does more than one developer work on this application? If so, sharing one large file might create a problem. Do you find navigating one large file in a editor difficult?

Comment: @DaveB yes, I'm working in a team, but this doesn't matter, as it is the result of the Grunt build process. There are two versions build by our configuration, one release and another one that is not minified, compressed (and would not be inlined), so this isn't a problem

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is actually a really good question.

The only major drawback I can see is caching.

You can't cache your CSS or JavaScript neatly, and you have to somehow invalidate the cache on all of your page (including JS and CSS) on every change to any of them.

I might even take it one step further and inline all your images using **[Data URIs](http://css-tricks.com/data-uris/)**, the reasoning being that extra HTTP requests are more expensive than loading an additional ~33% of data, thanks to how TCP works (It starts slowly, then exponentially increases download speed until packets begin to get lost), an extra few KBs at the top speed might just be better than a bunch of new requests.

Comment: the whole HTML page is cached, and changes are detected using the ETag header. There won't be many changes (fixed release-cycles and inspection windows for the productive system), and the largest part are CSS and JS, which would need to be updated nevertheless in case of any change

Comment: Go for it then. It's an interesting approach, and I would be interested if you did some benchmarking once you released and then see if it's actually better. I suspect that it will. Also check my edit for a twist ;)

Comment: thanks, I will try it and post some benchmark results afterwards ;)

Comment: Careful with overdoing it on the data uris, the [performance on mobile devices is terrible](http://www.mobify.com/blog/data-uris-are-slow-on-mobile/): "For recent, high-end smartphones such as those running iOS 6 or Android 4.2, binary image materialization is about 6x faster. For older, slower hardware, binary image materialization is 10x faster..."

Comment: @steveax Good point! Haven't thought of mobile. Could you edit that detail into my answer?

Comment: The _major drawback_ is what I actually see as a _major reason_ to do this. Sure, if you update your SPA quite often, you have to transfer _everything_ again just to update your client side. However, if your SPA stays as it is for a while, a lot of requests regarding cache won't even need to be invoked and you'll save all those dummy requests resulting in 304 status code replies. And depending on your code base and external libraries those are usually more than just a few dozen ....

Answer (score 3):

Yes. It is actually recommended by Google if the CSS resources are small. (note: this only applies to CSS)

> Modern browsers block on external CSS before painting content to the screen. This incurs additional network latency and increases the time it takes to display content to the screen. To optimize the time to render, if the external CSS resources are small, you can insert those directly into the HTML document. Inlining small CSS in this way allows the browser to proceed with rendering the page.

https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/InlineCSS

Obviously, you would keep these resources separate during development and use some build tool like gulp/grunt.

Answer (score 0):

No, you should not inline the CSS and JavaScript with HTML. Separate resources will be cached. Think separation of concerns! How would you run the JavaScript through something like JSLint? How would you validate the CSS when it is all inline?

Comment: There **is** separation of concerns in the source code and the debug version. I'm talking about the release output of grunt ('never look at auto-generated code')

Comment: @DaveB Think of the code the client sees as compiled code, while the sources are kept well separated and neat. The idea is only to increase the loading speed by reducing the number of HTTP requests.

Comment: @SecondRikudo Thanks, I see the point. I didn't realize this when I posted my answer. Is there any impact on client side debugging?

Comment: I generally have two "sites", one is "production" and the other is "development". The development site has all code unminified and fully blown, where you can easily do the debugging. Production site is never debugged.

Answer (score 0):

Leave your CSS and JS separate. If there are changes to your HTML but not your CSS, you're asking your user to download all of your CSS again. If the CSS is a separate file, then the browser will use the locally cached version, no extra trips to the server required.

If you're using grunt, use a task like [grunt-filerev](https://github.com/yeoman/grunt-filerev) to add a hash to your CSS and JS filenames once they are minified and concatenated.

Comment: IF the changes are spaced enough, the impact of that is minimal.

Answer (score -2):

If you inline the JS and CSS in the SPA html itself, you will end up with un-maintainable code along with the issue of browser not being able to cache CSS and JS files.

If you are using grunt to prepare build, why don't you just create many small JS and CSS files like we do in regular apps and then use **grunt-contrib-concat** to concatenate (maybe also minify) them into a single file and have that as a reference in your HTML.

Let me know if you need some sample code on this.

Comment: please see my edit. The application is not (can not be) updated often, and I won't manually inline any code. It is a technical question, and only about what might improve the browser performance or user experience.